# Infragistics IgniteUI IGFileUpload doesn't upload files to the server in ASP.NET MVC CORE 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0, ignite-ui

Lets say I have a simple `Index.cshtml` View:

```
<link href="~/libs/JQueryUI/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/libs/infragistics/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/libs/infragistics/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using CommonLib.Source.Common.Converters
@using CommonLib.Source.Common.Extensions
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<div id="chart" style="color: blue"></div>

<div id="indicator"></div>

<div id="igFileUpload" style="color: blue"></div>

<script src="~/libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/JQueryUI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/infragistics/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/infragistics/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/Lightweight-Charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.development.js"></script>
<script src="~/MyScripts.js"></script>

@(
    Html.Infragistics().Upload()
        .ID("igFileUpload")
        .Mode(UploadMode.Multiple)
        .AutoStartUpload(true)
        .ProgressUrl(Context.GetAbsoluteUrl("~/IGUploadStatusHandler.ashx"))
        .UploadUrl(Context.GetAbsoluteUrl("~/Data/UploadedFiles")) // just use Url.Content for testing purposes
        .ControlId("serverID1")
        .Width("600px")
        .Render()
)

<div id="error-message" style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#igFileUpload").bind({ iguploadonerror: function (e, args) {
                $("#error-message").html(args.errorMessage).stop(true, true).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also got `Startup.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using CommonLib.Source.Common.Utils;
using Infragistics.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CryptoBotCoreMVC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            //services.Configure<UploadAppSettings>(options =>
            //{
            //    options.FileUploadPath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Data"; //WebUtils.GetWebAppAbsolutePath("
            //}); // TODO: fu doesn't work | FileUploadPath is set in the View because it is too early to do it here
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider svp)
        {
            WebUtils.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), env); 
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseUploadModuleMiddleware();
            app.UseUploadHandlerMiddleware();
            app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider($@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Data"),
                RequestPath = "/Data",
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Reference here:
https://www.igniteui.com/help/using-igniteui-controls-in-asp.net-core-1.0-project

To be safe I set maximum file size in `web.config`:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!-- 1 GB -->
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and in IIS:

[image]

This is what Fiddler shows:

[image]

1st:

[image]

2nd and 3rd:

[image]

According to this: 
https://www.igniteui.com/help/igupload-using-http-handler-and-modules 
The error means:

```
Status: 3 - File not found - this status is used when it is not found such key in the dictionary
Error: 5 - File does not exist with the specified key in the request
```

Here is the result itself:

[image]

Here is the reference for the control documentation (some of it is not applicable for `ASP.NET CORE`):

https://www.igniteui.com/help/igupload-igupload 
https://www.igniteui.com/file-upload/overview

The problem is that as you can see, while the control works, the files are not actually uploaded to the server. I don't believe this is a bug, I think that I am not familiar enough with `CORE 3.0` and I am missing something rather obvious in configuration of `IGUploadStatusHandler.ashx`.
I would rather want to avoid digging for IF default Web Handler code if possible.

/EDIT

As per @MasLoo suggestion I implemented the middleware to replace the apparently required `IgnoreRoute` but I fail to understand how throwing 404 directly from it would make the Handler work:

```
(...)
app.UseMiddleware<IgnoreRouteMiddleware>();
(...)
```

:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace CryptoBotCoreMVC.Middlewares
{
    public class IgnoreRouteMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public IgnoreRouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("IGUploadStatusHandler.ashx"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                return;
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

After doing a test it indeed throws 404 right away, actually twice:

[image]

On commenting the:

```
//context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

The fiddler catches this:

[image]

with the following message:

[image]

I didn't post the messages because they are exactly the same as the first one with `Content-Length: 0`.

Further ideas would be warmly welcome.

// EDIT 2

I think I am almost there, but not quite. I noticed that for some reason if I keep urls default, the IF Code instead of looking for a folder for files in `UploadUrl` it looks for `ig_fua34sf345sdf13sdf3454erdsf2345asd3425df5235d54df345.aspx` path so I changed my `HtmlHelper` into:

```
Html.Infragistics().Upload()
    .ID("igFileUpload")
    .Mode(UploadMode.Multiple)
    .AutoStartUpload(true)
    .ProgressUrl(Context.GetAbsoluteUrl("~/IGUploadStatusHandler.ashx"))
    .UploadUrl(Context.GetAbsoluteUrl("~/ig_fua34sf345sdf13sdf3454erdsf2345asd3425df5235d54df345.aspx"))
    .ControlId("serverID1")
    .Width("600px")
    .Render()
```

and now I am getting 500s:

[image]

with the following Stack Trace:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 00:17:16 GMT
Content-Length: 1398

System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.MiddleWare.UploadModuleMiddleware.ReadFully(Stream input)
   at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.MiddleWare.UploadModuleMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at CryptoBotCoreMVC.Middlewares.IgnoreRouteMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in <Path>\CSharp\Projects\CryptoBotCoreMVC\CryptoBotCoreMVC\Middlewares\IgnoreRouteMiddleware.cs:line 23
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 244
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary3RFkBWmZhhsbjzXr
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost/CryptoBotCoreMVC
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
```

Now we are getting somewhere, it seems that changing `Kestrel` or `IIS` configuration should be sufficient in this case:

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
```

and indeed it is, I am gonna post detailed answer soon.

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.igniteui.com/help/igupload-overview) in MVC projects you'll need to ignore route to HTTP handler.

Comment: IgnoreRoute isn't available in ASP.NET CORE 3.0 afaik.

Comment: Right, It's not available in whole .net core (either in core 1.0). you can implement it as a middleware.

Comment: Updated my post to include your suggestions @MasLoo, I would appreciate further assistance.

Comment: What's wrong with this line: `options.FileUploadPath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Data";`? is it error prone too?

Comment: If I set physical path, it doesn't respect the setting and if I set a virtual one it would require me to have access either to `WebContentPath` or to `HttpContext` and it is way to early for that because both are null. If I set it to the whole address with the path it will throw 404s the same way as it throws now. For this reason I am setting the `UploadUrl` in `Html` helper and it seems to be doing ok.

Comment: How did you use IgniteUI in asp.net core 3.0? As [IgniteUI ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IgniteUI/19.1.39), it depends on `.NETFramework 4.0`.

Comment: `IngiteUI` doesn't need `.NET CORE` nor `.NET Framework` actually (it contains only `*.js` and `.css` files) - `Infragistics.Web.MVC` on the other hand (which includes `HtmlHelper` extensions) does and it supports `.NET CORE` (it is even in the documentation I linked in my post). Also a Fun fact: you can reference packages from `.NET Framework` in `.NET Core 3.0` if you wish, I am doing it all the time with `MahApps` in my own `WPF CORE 3.0` projects. @Tao Zhou, do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make `IgUpload` Control from `IgniteUI` work with `ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.0` you need to perform the following steps (Be aware however that it still isn't streaming large files in chunks, for this refer to [this](https://www.igniteui.com/help/igupload-saving-files-as-stream) article (which hasn't been updated for `ASP.NET CORE`)):

1. Add `Infragistics.Web.AspNetCore` and `IgniteUI` NuGet packages OR add the scripts, `.css` files and `.dll` file manually from your `Infragistics` installation folder as dependencies:

   [image]
2. Set `maxAllowedContentLength` in `web.config` file:

   [image]
3. Set `Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)` in `IIS`: `CTRL + R` > `inetmgr` > `<Server or Website>` > `IIS Category` > `RequestFiltering` > `Actions Pane (to the right side)` > `Edit Feature Settings...`
4. Include `options.AllowSynchronousIO = true` in your `Startup.cs` file for `Kestrel` and/or `IIS` to prevent `Middleware` from throwing `Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead` exception.
5. Set `maxFileSizeLimit` to a positive value, because despite the documentation statement it will not work for larger files if you set it to `null`, `-1` or if you won't set this option at all.
6. Set `FileUploadPath` to a Physical Directory on the application Drive (not the Virtual one).

   [image]
7. Render the Control including `ProgressUrl`, `UploadUrl` and `ControlID` options and set them to the exact values visible below to prevent `Middleware` from throwing various inxeplicit `404` errors (code samples will be on the bottom of this answer).

   [image]
8. Get the desired result:

   [image]

**IMPORTANT: `IgnoreRoute` is NOT required!**

Code samples:

`Startup.cs`:

```
using System.IO;
using Infragistics.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace IgUpload
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
            services.Configure<UploadAppSettings>(options =>
            {
                options.maxFileSizeLimit = "1073741824"; // 1 GB
                options.FileUploadPath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Data\UploadedFiles";
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseUploadModuleMiddleware();
            app.UseUploadHandlerMiddleware();
            app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));
        }
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div id="igFileUpload"></div>

<script src="~/libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/JQueryUI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/infragistics/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script src="~/libs/infragistics/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

@(
    Html.Infragistics().Upload()
        .ID("igFileUpload")
        .Mode(UploadMode.Multiple)
        .AutoStartUpload(true)
        .ProgressUrl(Url.Content("~/IGUploadStatusHandler.ashx"))
        .UploadUrl(Url.Content("~/ig_fua34sf345sdf13sdf3454erdsf2345asd3425df5235d54df345.aspx"))
        .ControlId("serverID1")
        .Width("600px")
        .Render()
)

<div id="error-message" style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#igFileUpload").bind({ iguploadonerror: function (e, args) {
                $("#error-message").html(args.errorMessage).stop(true, true).fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```